# How to fix the “pending” status in Chrome Developer Window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, social-networking

When I try to include social media scripts into my page, I get the "pending" status in Chrome on some computers (not all of them):
[image: chrome developer window]
https://s17.postimg.cc/xvpjllmwv/image.png

In other words, the scripts are not loaded. The scripts are included via the default way as recommended by the developer's guide.

What settings of Chrome may cause such behavior?

Comment: Are you including them from a local server of from a local HTML file?

Comment: any specific version ? Or some plugin or security setting that may be blocking the access to the library.

Comment: @Anzeo: No, it's a live standard website. It works for the most people but some of them reports that they have the given problem.

Answer (score 19):

This is due to the Ad-block or some plugin you are using with the chrome. Disabling the ad-block/plugin which blocks the requests will fix your issue. It blocks all the requests and so it is pending.

Try to fix this way and share the status.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But unfortunately, there are not any extra extensions installed or ad-block plugins installed on Chrome.

Comment: @JeanLouis are you sure this is true for all your users?

Comment: As far as I have found such issues, reasons I identified were the same I have mentioned. @JeanLouis

Comment: Is there anything perhaps a `attribute` that will tell add block that this is not a ad?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using HTTPS on the site?

If you are, chrome blocks http requests within https websites and shows a gray shield near the bookmark star on the url bar.

If this is the case just include your external stuff without specifying protocols

Example:

Change

http://domain.com/some.js to //domain.com/some.js

Answer (score 3):

Answer repeated from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window/28589598#28589598) question.

I had the same issue on OSX Mavericks, it turned out that Sophos anti-virus was blocking certain requests, once I uninstalled it the issue went away.

You can also try disabling extensions in chrome to see if that helps, if so you'll know an extension is causing the problem. Use the '--disable-extensions flag to see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using AngularJS as a front-end framework for my app, and somehow `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` made all my `POST` requests pending. After I removed this line, everything run instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the script takes more time in loading while the system has moved on. so make sure you wait for get to give you response before you manipulate it.
so rather then doing following

```
var temp;
$.get('path/to/filename.ext',function(data){

temp = data;

}
//use temp
```

do this

```
    var temp;
$.get('path/to/filename.ext',function(data){
temp = data;
//use temp
}
```