# image is always pending on Angular JS view

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm having problem with my view, it seems that the image is always pending and it's not been rendered by the browser.

I have this folder structure:

```
img/
 - logo.png
scripts/
 - scripts here
styles/
 - stylesheets here
views/
 - home.html
index.html
```

in my views/home.html I have this code to render the logo:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="Note Card" class="img-responsive">
```

the view has been successfully rendered but the image is missing/not rendered.
Based on my console it seems logo.png is always pending.

Any thoughts on how to make this work? I can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's my browser that's causing the trouble. I've tried doing Incognito mode, and the image got loaded.

**tl;dr Delete the cache**

Comment: I had the same behavior as you're describing - wouldn't load in normal Chrome tab, would load in Incognito. Restarting Chrome fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing src="img/logo.png" to src="/img/logo.png"? 
Not familiar with Angular but your code is referencing a img dir under views.
Adding the leading slash will start it from your root.

Comment: It doesn't work, even with `../img/logo.png`. According from the docs the angular view is relative to the index.html, therefore I'll just have to use `img/logo.png`. But it's not working. The browser says that the image is "pending". I have tried checking the link and it points correctly to the file.

Comment: Do you have any AdBlock extensions, etc? It seems pending means that either there is a network problem or the image is being blocked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window

Comment: Thanks!
It seems it's my browser that's causing the trouble. I've tried doing Incognito mode, and the image got loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-src attribute in the img tag..

html:

```
    <img ng-src={{imageUrl}} alt="Note Card" class="img-responsive">
```

controller:

```
    $scope.imageUrl="img/logo.png";
```

Check this document:
      Click [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)