# My sounds are not playing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

I have a small, very basic 3d game that runs in all browsers. But my issue is that when it runs in Chrome I can see in my console messages that the sounds are "pending" and don't play when they should. The thing is that after some time have passed ALL sounds play at the same time. It doesn't seem to be happening anywhere else, its just in Chrome. I came across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window) that someone posted but it did not solve my issue. Just in case I am running **Version 43.0.2357.81 m**  of Chrome and I am using the Sound Manager 2 library (I needed it in order to have sound work with IE 9 and up).

Can anyone offer some suggestions or point me to any more articles that might point me to a solution? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post some code generating the issue one may be able to help you out. Have you tried when disabling all extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on logging in Chrome (inspect element/console - Preserve log) and see what your code is doing.

Also, you could try enabling/disabling your audio flags just be sure to set them back to default when you are done.
chrome://flags/#disable-encrypted-media
chrome://flags/#disable-prefixed-encrypted-media/
chrome://flags/#try-supported-channel-layouts
chrome://flags/#enable-delay-agnostic-aec
chrome://flags/#disable-delay-agnostic-aec
chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting

in chrome and see if that makes a difference.

Just shooting from the hip on the information given though, I would imagine that chrome is delaying your audio javascript execution to the end of the page load.  Moving the script to the beginning of the page, or using an async could fix this.  Here is a good resource for javascript page load issues: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

Comment: thank you, my buddies/teammates here at home are getting a kick out of this article. It's insightful and I know its going to help us figure this out.

Comment: Great! I am glad it is helping. Javascript page load issues are one of the more frustrating things to deal with.

Comment: same problem for me here but the answer did not do the trick for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709069/ember-app-not-playing-sound-in-chrome

Comment: Koala7, looking at your issue, it sounds a little different than what was being experienced here (namely everything playing all at once after a few minutes). I see that you found an answer to your issue though, which is great!