# Http Request going into pending state most of the time

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am facing an issue the http get call going into pending state, basically i am hitting the server for that http get call after every 5 seconds, that call getting latitude and longitude from server and rendering map based on those lat lng. The problem is call most of the time goes into pending state and making queue of that specific call because that call have to be called after every 5 seconds, one call stuck the others all dependent to that also stuck, the reason is javascript is a single threaded language, which will wait for a call to complete and run next when previous completed.

Kindly guide me How to debug that problem.

[image]

Comment: Please share use some Code and Screenshots of your Networkcalls.

Comment: Angular is perfectly capable of making asynchronous calls to a webserver. Have you looked at this http tutorial? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: @Stefan no, let me read that .

Comment: @lukasrein97 
 `Get_tracking_info(id){
        return this.http.get('URL/'+id+'/track',{headers: this.Get_Header()});
    }`

Comment: http.get is an asynchronous, you should not assume that it should return the results within 5 second. Because it is async, it may be longer than 5 second to fetch the result from the server. You may need to return observable from your factory and then subscribe the method after the response has been finished.

Comment: @digit now i am just returning the response and subscribed to that, could you provide any example related as you described return observable from factory?

Comment: @lukasrein97 please have look on screen short  i taken while pending status from network tab.

Comment: @UmarRasheed, is 1.9 min response time ? Also your every 5 sec call may  result in server thinking that its scrapper or attack

Comment: @N0mi so what should i need to do?

Comment: If you don't own the server side, better make a batch queries or check with provider, how frequent can you make the call.

Comment: @N0mi if i own the server side, what i can do for that to resolve pending issue because back end his written in ROR?

Comment: Did you check that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window

Comment: @N0mi yes checked that,