# AngularJS http get request is pending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am running the following code...

```
        $http.get(cmdUrl, {async: true, cache: false}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.logText = data;
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.logText = "An error occurred";
          });
```

When I run my application, I have a button that when clicked will invoke the get() method above.  The first time the button is clicked, the success callback runs successfully.  My problem is that when I click the button a second time I get no response.
I stepped through the code with a (Chrome) debugger and I see that I get a status code of 200 after the first invocation but on every subsequent call, the request is in a pending state.  Furthermore, while stepping through the code, on each subsequent request neither the success or the error callback are executed.  Also, after a while, I guess the pending requests time out and in the console, I see a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for each of requests that were pending.

I want to know why the subsequent get's are put in pending state and how can I get them to execute to completion.

Thanx!!!

This is the code on the server side of things written using NodeJS...

```
   app.get('/cmdURL', function(req, resp, next) {
       var intercept = require('intercept-stdout');
       var deasync = require('deasync');

       var captured_text = "";
       var unhook_intercept = intercept(function(txt) {
           captured_text += txt;
       });
       var logs = [];                                              
       var responseText = "";                                      
       var done = false;                                           

       var hook_stream = function(_stream, fn) {
           // Reference default write method
           var old_write = _stream.write;
           // _stream now write with our shiny function
           _stream.write = fn;

           return function() {
               // Reset to the default write method
               _stream.write = old_write;
           };
       };

       // Set hook for standard output
       var unhook_stdout = hook_stream(process.stdout, function(string, encoding, fd) {
           if (string.includes("-- end of response --")) done = true;             
           logs.push(string);                                      
       });

       var command = req.query.text;                               
       if (command) {
           var valid = issueCommand(command);

           if (valid) {
               while(!done) {
                   deasync.sleep(200);
               }
               unhook_stdout();

               console.log('Not hooked anymore.');

               // Now do what you want with logs stored by the hook
               logs.forEach(function(_log) {
                   responseText += _log;
               });
           }
           else {
               unhook_stdout();
               responseText += "Unrecognized command";
           }

           resp.status(200).send(responseText);
       }
       else {
           console.log('No command was specified.');
           resp.status(404).send('No command was specified.');
       }
   });

   function issueCommand(cmd) { 
      // Issue an asynchronous cmd
   }
```

Comment: which version of angularjs are you using? 'success' is already obsolete, it works with 'then'

Comment: Sorry, my example is being run using AngularJS v1.5.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "pending" mean for request in Chrome Developer Window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window)

Comment: Can you show us more code. Is this method a part of service ?

Comment: After reading, this does not seem to be the same issue as the Chrome Developer Window issue.  By the way, this also occurs in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

[What does "pending" mean for request in Chrome Developer Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window)

Comment: The above solution yielded the same results as my original implementation.
The function at **cmdUrl** which returns the response data can some times be an asynchronous function.