# 'Pending' in Chrome's Network when loading file from cache

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

[Chromes Network Section showing Pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVSyM.png)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "pending" mean for request in Chrome Developer Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your content is not load from cache so that's why it shows pending.
Don't try to get resource from cache.
May be .htaccess file helps you for that

Thanks

Comment: I am using Node.js as server side code ...is there any equivalent to .htaccess

Comment: .htaccess file is common for all server side scripting.
you can use it

Comment: Thanks..One more thing ...How can i change (from memory cache) to (disk cache)

Comment: do not store cache for your site so automatically it will work.